# Accessing server file system through URL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an ec2 instance. Since it was started I was able to access the instance through the public DNS (in the browser) just fine. I initially set the instance up as I needed to host a php script that one of my applications connected with.

Recently, I hosted another app on the box but wanted the app (node app listening on port 8080) to be accessible through a domain I purchased and so I associated my instance with an elastic IP and then connected it to my domain. I then used nginx to forward requests to port 8080 which my app was listening on. Everything works great.

Now, the issue is that I can no longer access my php script through the original URL (publicdns/somefolder/file.php). My initial thought was that this was to be expected and so I tried elasticip/somefolder/file.php. Still no luck. How can I access this script in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You should have differet vhosts/server blocks for each hostname. You should serve example.com on port 80 as normal and only reverse proxy to port 8080 for otherdomain.example.com.